# De-Angularize a hefty databound table

Tags: angularjs

We have a data-bound table that is dynamically built from an array of objects. There are 2 loops, one for columns and one for rows. There are some filters for formatting for each cell based on the type of data. Without paging the page comes down to its knees pretty soon with about 600 records or so. Chrome is OK but IE is not. I did remove the filters etc. but it is not making a huge difference.

I think the Angular nature of the binding is slowing it down. Is there a way to just do a one way binding / templating that does not have the additional overhead that comes with the normal bindings? Something similar to Handlebars? I can probably write a directive that takes care of that but would like to use something built in if possible.

Extra Note: I don't think I have the option to use some other pre-built datagrid as we have our own look and feel in the app and I would rather not try to customize that to fit in.

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism for doing that kind of binding and I'm not sure I see the value; how would you react with the data table without the bindings? I think you'd have to use some dirty hacks. You could use a directive, yes, but I think you should find out what's slowing your code down; AngularJS should be okay in modern browsers up to thousands of bindings. Also, you may want to reconsider showing hundreds of rows at a time - it's just no longer helpful for a human user.

Comment: We really don't need interaction within the grid. So simple template merging would do. Also we do have paging at 50 records per page. That is not really an issue. I was just curious though, in case we ended up showing 200 or more records per page. Chrome is OK but IE8 really starts to slow down at 200 X 20 grid.

Comment: Well, I can't speak to IE...fortunately. :-) A directive would be the best way to go, but there are *tons* of caveats when you don't have the data bindings. Creating new HTML from a template is precisely what directives are for. Bindings are just that - they bind things together. You could write your own highly simplified version of ngRepeat to do what you want to do, but because of the caveats I mentioned, I'm not sure a general-purpose directive of this type would be feasible - so it'll need to be a custom job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found a few options of various difficulties.

Pasquale Vazzana has written an excellent directive called bind-once, which does not keep any watches to your bindings thus reducing the overhead.

https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

This should work for small to mid-sized tables (<5000 cells).

On larger tables, virtualization (infinite scrolling / virtual scrolling etc.) is the way to go.

Jquery EasyUI provides a datagrid with a Virtual Scrolling option
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=

Hope this helps someone in the same boat.